# Aptana: find and replace tabs (with spaces)

Tags: aptana, whitespace

I am belatedly setting up Aptana to use four spaces instead of tabs. I've made the necessary changes to the preferences so every new tab inserts four spaces.

All the existing tabs remain, however, and so I get `Mixed spaces and tab` errors. How can you do a `Replace all` to fix this? I've tried `^t`, `<TAB>` etc but it just searches for these as normal strings. What are the correct ways to specify a space and a tab?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've found myself in similar situation and copying whole source code and repasting it helped me out. Just do as follow on your source code <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then <kbd>Del</kbd> whole code and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> it again. You will get only spaces if have set it in options like you mentioned above.

Answer (score 5):

There's an option in the <s>refactor</s> source menu to convert between tabs and space-tabs.

Comment: Fantastic! Ummm... where's the `refactor menu`? I can't find it!

Comment: Err, sorry, I meant the source menu.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)  My source menu (in 3.1.3...) only allows `Format` and offers no options. I tried it, but it doesn't seem to change the tabs :(

Comment: I did it! You just select all, cut and re-paste and it formats it for you :)

Comment: No! Not at all. Maybe the Mac version is less fancy :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: *Edit > Find/Replace...* (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), check Regular Expressions, type `\t` and type 4 spaces (I use 4 spaces for tab).